# \rule at the end of line not properly justified

Tags: rules

I have a list of items with and need for the gaps at the end of the sentence.

But sometimes rule is not properly justified if it's at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The number of people in the poorest half of the world's population: \rule[-0.1mm]{2.5cm}{0.1mm}

\item The decrease in wealth of the poorest half of the world's popu: \rule[-0.1mm]{2.5cm}{0.1mm}\ %
\item The number of people with the same wealth as the poorest half of the population in 2010: \rule[-0.1mm]{2.5cm}{0.1mm}\ %
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any idea to to force to make it right?

Comment: `\hrulefill` might do something similar to what you're looking for, but of course a less manual solution would be much more elegant.

Comment: Try to read the TeX log. What is here: Overfull \hbox warning. Why? Because the rule is unbreakable box here. What is your intend in the first line? To compress the line? There is no space to such compression. Or to put the rule to the next line and put the word "population" at the end of first line? Spaces between words will be horrible large. The automaton doesn't know what to do, therefore it puts the Overfull message and leaves the paragraph unsolved (with overlapping box). Human must specify exactly, what to do here.

Comment: The idea is to keep the rule with the fixed length. If it doesn't fit it should go to the next line and the text in the previous line should be justified.

Comment: @Luman75 -- The fact that the rule should be fixed length is important information, and should go in the question.  Then it will remain available in case comments get removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Werner uses a position measurement (needs two TeX runs and pdfTeX extension) and Bernard shows that a LaTeX pakage can be used. Both solutions leaves a space right in the problematic line. OK. If this is desired behavior (it was not specified by OP) then I show the solution based on TeX primitives, which seems to be simple and more straightforward.

```
\newdimen \rulewd   \rulewd=2.5cm
\def\myrule{\hskip0pt plus\rulewd\penalty0\hskip0pt plus-\rulewd \hbox to\rulewd{\hrulefill}}
```

The main core of this solution calls "discardable items". TeX can break the line at the `\penalty0`, i.e. before the rule itself. If it is done then the following discardable item `\hskip0pt plus-\rulewd` is discarded and the preceding item `\hskip 0pt plus\rulewd` does the space at the end of the line. If the breaking point isn't at the `\penalty0`, then the following `\hskip0pt plus-\rulewd` cancels the activity of previous `\hskip0pt plus\rulewd` and only the rule is placed here.

Answer (score 2):

`\rule[<raise>]{<length>}{<width>}` sets a rule of length `<length>` and thickness `<width>`, raised by `<drop>` (`0pt` is the default). It acts like a single character (or box) just like anything else on the same line would. So, placing it at the end of a sentence should allow it to break as usual, except if it's too long and there doesn't seem to be an optimal way to make it break (the `\rule` as a whole) to the following line.

Below I define `\answerrule` that sets a `\rule` of length 25mm on the same line it is placed within the code, except if the rule doesn't fit. Then it inserts a `\par`agraph break *before* inserting the `\rule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{showframe}% Just to show the text block boundary

\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\newcounter{answercnt}
\newcommand{\answerrule}{%
  \stepcounter{answercnt}%
  \zsaveposx{answer-\theanswercnt}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\hoffset+1in+\oddsidemargin+\leftmargin+\linewidth-\zposx{answer-\theanswercnt}sp<25mm
    \par\nobreak
  \fi
  \rule[-0.1mm]{25mm}{0.1mm}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item The number of people in the poorest half of the world's population: \answerrule

  \item The decrease in wealth of the poorest half of the world's population: \answerrule

  \item The number of people with the same wealth as the poorest half of the population in 2010: \answerrule
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `linegoal`, with the help of `etoolbox`. The length of 2.5cm is the default value of the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\newlength{\remain}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\myrule}[1][2.5cm]{\setlength{\remain}{\linegoal}\ifdimless{\remain}{#1}{\newline}{} \rule[-0.1mm]{#1}{0.1mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The number of people in the poorest half of the world's population: \myrule
\item The decrease in wealth of the poorest half of the world's popu: \myrule%
\item The number of people with the same wealth as the poorest half of the population in 2010: \myrule
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]